# Static class memeber to array

Tags: c#

How can I get an array with all static Strings of a class inside?

**What I have:**

```
public static class A
{
    public static class BA
    {
        public const string BAA = "baa";
        public const string BAB = "bab";
        public const string BAC = "bac";
    }
    public static class BB
    {
        public const string BBA = "bba";
        public const string BBB = "bbb";
        public const string BBC = "bbc";
    }
}
```

**What I want:**

```
string[] BAs = new string[]{"baa","bab","bac"};
string[] BBs = new string[]{"bba","bbb","bbc"};
```

**Would be nice too (but prefer solution above):**

```
string[] BAs = new string[]{"BAA","BAB","BAC"};
string[] BBs = new string[]{"BBA","BBB","BBC"};
```

**Some pseudo code:**

```
string[] BAs = A.BA.GetAllStringVariablesFromStaticMembers();
string[] BBs = A.BB.GetAllStringVariablesFromStaticMembers();
```

Is this possible at all? And if it is, how can I do it?

**Additional information:** The static classes just contain static strings inside, so a general member method is possible too, but I prefer if the method returns just the static strings of the given class.

Comment: Why not just use the code you wrote? Put all the strings into an array to begin with.

Comment: Because I need to access the variables by the keys and as a list/array. I want to use the variables as dynamic constants to improve my code and to reduce my errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via ***Reflection*** with a *slightly different syntax*:

```
public static String[] GetAllStringVariablesFromStaticMembers(Type value) {
  if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, value))
    throw new ArgumentNullException("value");

  List<String> result = new List<String>();

  foreach (FieldInfo fi in value.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)) 
    if (fi.FieldType == typeof(String))
      result.Add(fi.GetValue(null) as String);

  return result.ToArray();
}

...

string[] BAs = GetAllStringVariablesFromStaticMembers(typeof(A.BA));
```

Comment: Good answer, but, frankly, if he's interested in readability, then using Reflection won't do that for him.

Comment: @John Saunders: Yes, I absolutly agree with your comment that putting all the strings into array or dictionary (string's name + string) is much better design.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class TypeExtension
{
    public static string[] GetStaticStrings(this Type type)
    {
        return type
                 .GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                 .Where(field => field.FieldType == typeof(string))
                 .Select(field => (string)field.GetValue(null))
                 .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string[] arr = typeof(A.BA).GetStaticStrings();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you require. Basically you need an instance of a class to do `A.BA` since BA will either be a property of a field which will point to an instance.

```
public static class A {
    public static readonly A_Wrapper BA = new A_Wrapper(
        new string[3] {
            "baa",
            "bab",
            "bac"
        }
    );

        public static readonly A_Wrapper BB = new A_Wrapper(
        new string[3] {
            "bba",
            "bbb",
            "bbc"
        }
    );

    public class A_Wrapper {
        public A_Wrapper(string[] data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
        private readonly string[] data;
        public string[] GetAllStringVariablesFromStaticMembers() {
            return data;
        }
    }
}

var data1 = A.BA.GetAllStringVariablesFromStaticMembers(); // baa, bab, bac
var data2 = A.BB.GetAllStringVariablesFromStaticMembers(); // bba, bbb, bbc
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this doesn't work for me because I need to access the variables by the keys and as a list/array (I cant modify my structure as shown above). I want to use the variables as dynamic constants to improve my code and to reduce my errors.